# wpf, how can i get template element on custom-controls, after new instance immediately

Tags: wpf, templates, custom-controls, element

questions:

1、i wanna get template elements when calling the constructor, but return null, any way?

2、i found it, get not null obj after loaded event, but i don't want this way.

snippet code:(to see my comments)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfPropertyGrid_Demo
{
    public class MyButton : Control
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMouseDownProperty;

        static MyButton()
        {
            IsMouseDownProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "IsMouseDown",
                typeof(bool),
                typeof(MyButton),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false)
                );
        }

        public bool IsMouseDown
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsMouseDownProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsMouseDownProperty, value); }
        }

        private BitmapImage _normalImg;
        private BitmapImage _overImg;
        private BitmapImage _clickImg;
        private BitmapImage _disabledImg;

        public MyButton()
        {
            _normalImg = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../../Images/ScrollerBtnBg.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            _overImg = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../../Images/ScrollerThumbnailBtnBg.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            _clickImg = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../../Images/ScrollerThumbnailBg.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            _disabledImg = _clickImg;

            var style = new Style(typeof(MyButton));
            var controlTemplate = new ControlTemplate();

            var gridFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
            var imgFacotry = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));
            imgFacotry.Name = "Image";
            imgFacotry.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, _normalImg);
            gridFactory.AppendChild(imgFacotry);

            controlTemplate.VisualTree = gridFactory;

            var overTrigger = new Trigger();
            overTrigger.Property = UIElement.IsMouseOverProperty;
            overTrigger.Value = true;
            overTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(Image.SourceProperty, _overImg, "Image"));

            var disabledTriiger = new Trigger();
            disabledTriiger.Property = UIElement.IsEnabledProperty;
            disabledTriiger.Value = false;
            disabledTriiger.Setters.Add(new Setter(Image.SourceProperty, _disabledImg, "Image"));

            var downTrigger = new Trigger();
            downTrigger.Property = MyButton.IsMouseDownProperty;
            downTrigger.Value = true;
            downTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(Image.SourceProperty, _clickImg, "Image"));

            controlTemplate.Triggers.Add(overTrigger);
            controlTemplate.Triggers.Add(disabledTriiger);
            controlTemplate.Triggers.Add(downTrigger);

            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.TemplateProperty, controlTemplate));
            this.PreviewMouseDown += new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(MyButton_PreviewMouseDown);
            this.PreviewMouseUp += new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(MyButton_PreviewMouseUp);
            this.MouseLeave += new System.Windows.Input.MouseEventHandler(MyButton_MouseLeave);
            this.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(MyButton_MouseEnter);

            Style = style;

            // 1、why cann't find "Image" element, it return null obj, i wanna get it immediately, any way?
            // 2、return not null after loaded event
            // var image = controlTemplate.FindName("Image", this );

            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MyButton_Loaded);
        }

        void MyButton_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            IsMouseDown = e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed;
        }

        void MyButton_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            IsMouseDown = false;
        }

        void MyButton_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            IsMouseDown = false;
        }

        void MyButton_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            IsMouseDown = true;
        }

        void MyButton_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // return not null after loaded event
            var image = this.Template.FindName("Image", this) as Image; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Visual Helper Class here](http://datagridas2dmatrix.wordpress.com/2013/11/30/accesing-wpf-datagrid-rows-and-columns-through-index/) I hope this will help

Comment: thks for your answer.but i try to this code:var image = VisualHelper.FindVisualChildByName<Image>(this, "Image");//also return null before adding loaded event code